# Pipe output to parameter

Tags: unix, pipe

So I wanted to write a simple command that counts one less than the number of files in my current directory. I have this command that comes close but is off by one.

```
ls | wc -l
```

How can I pipe this to `bc` so I can subtract it by one?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to subtract one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pipe to `bc` you could use something like this

```
echo " $(ls | wc -l) - 1 " | bc
```

EDIT: replace the part in the `$(` `)` with steve's answer, or any other command you need.

Comment: You should really [avoid parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Just use `find`.

Answer (score 0):

That's really not what you want to do. Use `find` instead:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

Also, you can exclude hidden files, with:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name ".*" | wc -l
```

For completeness, you can handle files containing newlines and spaces like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | tr -dc '\0' | wc -c
```